# My data training set score is 77%, validation set is 70%. Is this acceptable for 7% decline of validation set compared to the training set?

Tags: data-science

I am running the image segmentation on Unet. My data training set average 3D dice score is 77%, validation set is 70%. Is this acceptable for 7% decline of validation set compared to the training set? In addition, the testing set is 62%, is this overfitting or is it acceptable?

Comment: Depends on domain and your purpose.

Comment: It's under fitting and indicates possibility of either leakage or inadequate preprocessing.